# How to automatically retrieve pdf documents of a specific subject from web?

Tags: python, pdf, web

I have to download a large collection of pdf documents from web on a specific topic .

Is there any tool which can do this task for me

Comment: Do you have the URLs of the documents?

Comment: @nofinator.. I dont have the urls . I just know the area from which documents should be downloaded. For eg : Operating system , networks etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of possibilities provided that you have a list of URLs, e.g. wget, curl, python etc. With python standard library:

```
import urllib2
url_list = ['http://www.blah.com/1.pdf', 'http://www.blah.com/2.pdf'.....]
for url in list_of_urls:
    outfile = os.path.basename(url)
    with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
        print "Downloading %s to %s" % (url, outfile)
        out.write(urllib2.open(url).read())
```

Or you could look at the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

**EDIT**
You've added a comment that you don't have a predefined URL list. You need to query something to get a list of candidates, and then download them using one of the suggested methods, e.g. use [Google custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) to submit a search, and then analyze the JSON formatted results to construct a list of URLs to download.

If you need to parse HTML, then take a look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)